# Can mpi4py allow objects to be passed between processes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, mpi4py

I am trying to examine how `mpi4py` can pass objects among processes. Given the following program:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np
import sys

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()


class ROOT(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10

    def func(self, rank):
        print("Rank=%d is able to calculate the result: %d " % (rank, np.power(self.x, 2)))

obj= None
if rank == 0:
    obj = ROOT()
    comm.send(obj, dest=2)

if rank == 2:
    comm.recv(obj, source=0)
    obj.func(rank)
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 47, in <module>
    obj.func(rank)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'func'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that the job aborted, but has no info as to the process
that caused that situation.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Rank 2 is supposed to be able to make `obj.func` print out the message but something is wrong! Can someone explain how to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Obviously the execution reaches the "rank == 2" code before the "rank == 0", at which point `obj` is still `None`.

Comment: This is weird! I thought `if rank == 0` should be executed first as it is before `if rank == 2`

Comment: The `if` is executed sequentially and that is not weird. `rank` is assigned once at the beginning of the script, whatever value it has, when it gets to the first `if` if it is `== 0` then `obj` gets whatever `ROOT()` its returning; but if it is `!= 0`, it will stay `None` and if it happen to be `2`, then `obj`, which is still `None` is trying to be accessed as if it wasn't anymore. The only situation where this code could work is if `rank` is always `0` at the beginning and somehow (although I could not see how) this causes the value of `rank` to become `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong, just replace

```
comm.recv(obj, source=0)
```

with

```
obj = comm.recv(obj, source=0)
```

comm.recv does not modify obj in place.